# Implementing EL 2.2 on tomcat 6

Tags: jsf, tomcat, el, myfaces

I was trying to enable EL 2.2 on tomcat 6.0.41 on windows 7.

I read this: http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/HowToEnableEl22

and this: [JSF - call method with parameter (tomcat6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913438/jsf-call-method-with-parameter-tomcat6)

and this: [org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The function test must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017348/org-apache-jasper-jasperexception-the-function-test-must-be-used-with-a-prefix)

and also this: [Can EL 2.2 capable JSF web applications be deployed to shared Tomcat 6 hosting environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661255/can-el-2-2-capable-jsf-web-applications-be-deployed-to-shared-tomcat-6-hosting-e)

and tried to follow them all but with no luck, I still get the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /DashBoard.jsp(234,7) The function
> setSelectedExperiment must be used with a prefix when a default
> namespace is not specified

on this line of code:

```
action="#{dashBoardController.setSelectedExperiment(experiment)}"
```

I did the following:
downloaded the el jars from here:
http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/el/el-api/2.2/el-api-2.2.jar

http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/glassfish/web/el-impl/2.2/el-impl-2.2.jar

and put them under WEB-INF/lib

I removed el-api.jar from tomcat6/lib

i added this to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
     <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

all according to the guidelines in [apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/HowToEnableEl22)

Yet, as I said, I get the error above.

Comment: Hello BalusC, what is the "dupe for the right approach"? thanks

Comment: See top of question.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks. I reinstalled tomcat6, i did exactly what it says on the link, and yet - I get the same error...

Comment: What JARs do you have right now in `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: antlr-2.7.7.jar,combinatoricslib-2.0.jar,dom4j-1.6.1.jar,fits.jar,gson-2.2.4.jar,jarfitsobj.jar,jarh4obj.jar,jarh5obj.jar,jarhdf-2.10.1.jar
jarhdf5-2.10.1.jar,jarhdfobj.jar,jarnc2obj.jar,javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar,javax.faces.jar,javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar,jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar,jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar,jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
jhdfview.jar,jsch-0.1.51.jar,libsvm.jar,log4j-1.2.17.jar,mockito-all-1.9.5.jar,mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar,netcdf.jar,slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar,slf4j-nop-1.7.5.jar

Comment: Hm, looks okay. I'll reopen the question. You may want to improve it to include the new information.